# Am I applying this vector-based equation correctly to my dataset?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, tensor-calculus, vectors, calculus, data

A coworker and I need to perform what is probably a simple calculation with our data so that we can calculate something else.  However, our vector calculus skills are rusty and we don't know if we understand the calculation (there don't seem to be any examples out there).  It would be great if someone could please set us on the right track.

Here's an example of our data:

```
x      y      z         Total
26.78  -6.31  27.17     38.67
26.80  -5.79  27.33     38.72
26.75  -5.28  27.415    38.67
26.63  -4.79  27.41     38.52
26.45  -4.34  27.36     38.31
```

x, y, and z are components of "Total."  "Total" is the square root of the sum of squares of x, y, and z.  Each row represents a new time at which we collected the data.

The calculation we need is variance, from:

> var(A) = (< **A** ^2> - <**A**>^2) # "^2" is "squared." <> is "average."

which may be the same as:

```
var(A) = (<A•A> - <A><A>)
```

Question: how do we apply this to the data? Is this correct (I have used the notation I would use in Python)?

> ```
> first term = (np.dot(x, x) + np.dot(y, y) + np.dot(z, z))/len(x)
> second term = np.mean(np.square(Total))
> ```

Or should the second term be different, maybe:

```
second term = (sum of all x rows + sum of all y rows + sum of all z rows) • (sum of all x rows + sum of all y rows + sum of all z rows)
```

- If there is a more appropriate section for this question or better tags, it would be great to get a heads-up.

Comment: When in doubt,  test your implementation on a problem for which you know the solution. That is an easy way to check your calculation. It's often a good idea to test/debug your code with a simple problem whose solution you know and then to transfer it to your actual problem. Especially when the problem is mostly a question of indexing and array manipulations.

Comment: @HansWurst, thank you for your advice, Hans.  I would love to do that but don't know of a known solution.  I have seen the equation in various places so hope that there are people out there who know how to apply it.

Comment: It is unclear what you actually want to calculate. Do you want the variance of the total value or do you want variances of the components ? Can you define $\mathbf A$? Is $A=x+y+z$ or is $A=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. The variance of these two definitions are not the same.

Comment: @HansWurst, thank you.  As far as I know, the equation we need to use is as shown under this line in my question: "The calculation we need is variance, from:" A (in bold) is "Total," the square root of the sum of the squares as in your latter definition.  My apologies; I can't figure out how to add formatting to comments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about physics. You may try to ask it on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), which is the SE site for statistics, data analysis, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the values a list in Python, then you can simply use

```
Total_list = [38.67,  38.72, ...]
Total_var = np.var(Total_list)
```

which is equal to

```
Total_var = np.dot(Total_list,Total_list)/len(Total_list) - (np.sum(Total_list)/len(Total_list))**2
```

The first term is
$$
\langle A^2\rangle = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N A^2_i
$$
and the negative term is
$$
\langle A\rangle^2 = \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N A_i\right)^2
$$

This is the variance of the Total Value and corresponds to $A_i = \sqrt{x_i^2 + y_i^2 + z_i^2}$.

Equations can be typeset with Mathjax and the usage is explained here

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

But your question has nothing to do with physics and you would probably better of asking at https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I appreciate your clear explanation.  It sounds like you agree with me.  My coworker thinks that np.var does not treat the second term correctly, that it should instead be the dot product of the component averages at each time step (row).  I just don't see it.  I'll leave the question open for a while in case anyone else wants to comment.